# Page Specific Sass files and Duplication

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, sprockets

I am really struggling to structure the Sass files in a Rails 3.1 project to avoid massive duplication ...

I have the following structure, with application.css.scss being imported as part of my main layout:

```
application.css.scss
  - [*= require] main.css.scss
      - [@import] 'variables';
      - [@import]'bootstrap_overrides';
      - [@import]'bootstrap';
      - [@import]'base_elements';
      - [@import]'superstructure';
      - [@import]'modules';
```

So far so good. All these files are combined by sprockets into a single document. However I then want to modularise my Sass further, with page-specific files or files shared across regions of my site.

So on my GalleryResource#show page I need to use additional Sass files:

```
resource.scss
gallery_resource.scss
badges.scss
```

And maybe a css file from a lib:

```
gallery_lib.scss
```

These files need to reference a number of the files already imported in application.css. They need to make use of variables defined in variables.css.scss and of mixins defined in bootstrap. So I am forced to reimport these files in each file that uses them, causing massive duplication. I could write a manifest file for each and every page, but this is a maintenance nightmare and still results in duplication and two css files; application.css and page_specific.css.

So what is the solution? Do I need to dispence with application.css and move its imports into each page-specific file? So using the above example I would end up with a single manifest file that looks like this:

```
gallery_resource_manifest.css.scss
      - [*= require] gallery_lib.css
      - [*= require] gallery_resource.css.scss
         - [@import] 'variables';
         - [@import]'bootstrap_overrides';
         - [@import]'bootstrap';
         - [@import]'base_elements';
         - [@import]'superstructure';
         - [@import]'modules';
         - [@import]'resource';
         - [@import]'gallery_resource';
         - [@import]'gallery';
         - [@import]'badges';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by taking a cue from rspec, and creating a `_sass_helper.sass` partial, which contains all my non-direct-style imports (variables, mixins, placeholders), which is then included at the top of each file. The non-code bit is important, because if `_sass_helper.sass` contained any styles, they would be written into each file.

This effectively allows me to get the same "Sass environment" for each of my files, without any code duplication.

I have my tree organized like so:

```
includes/
  _variables.sass
  _mixins.sass
  _extends.sass
posts/
  _post_partial_1.sass
  _post_partial_2.sass
application.sass
posts.sass
_sass_helper.sass
```

Then, something like posts.sass would look like:

```
@import 'sass_helper'
@import 'posts/post_partial_1'
@import 'posts/post_partial_2'

.some.globally.shared.post
  styles: here
```

It works great. The post partials don't need the sass helper, so I end up with one master file per controller, with partials for individual features, and the same environment everywhere.

Comment: Sorry. Somehow missed your answer, and arrived at the same place through my own experimenting. It's worth pointing out that by separating out your mixins and variables into separate files from your selectors, you can effectively refer to them in repeated files without any duplication as it is only their values that are used by the files that reference them.

Comment: The one issue I've had with this technique is that if you have posts on the home page, posts on the articles page (and then posts elsewhere) you end up forcing the user to re-download the styles for posts multiple times. So you end up with the same problem you had initially but now you've lost the benefit of a cached file.

Comment: I solve those with a `posts/_shared.sass`, which is included in application rather than `posts`. I serve 2 CSS files per page (application and controller-specific), which is slightly suboptimal, but gets me no duplication and segments things nicely. I'm using the HTML5 appcache, as well, which mitigates much of that concern.

Comment: Great points Chris. After reviewing your method it seems like sass architecture would depend more on specific site styling and the size of your site. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I also attempted to do the same thing you are mentioning when organizing styles. Rails almost pushes you in this direction by constantly generating controller based stylesheets for you. In the end I've opted for adding everything to `application.sass`. The main advantage to this method is that you only make one request on page load and you don't end up having to re-import code that the user requested on the last page.

My personal opinion would be that if you abstract your CSS well you only need to use one stylesheet as you don't have a lot of view specific code to bring into the stylesheet in the first place. Either way, the alternative (randomly loading up modules based on page needs while you may have done the same on the previous page) doesn't sound like it's solving that problem anyway. Plus you are making more requests for completely new files.

CSS can be kind of tricky to organize. Here is an example of how I would typically organize my styles and also my stylesheets directory. This method works for a single namespace (application) or it can be broken out to work for multiple namespaces if need be (i.e. admin, application).

`application.sass`

```css
// vendor ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// compass

@import "compass/reset"
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow"
@import "compass/css3/border-radius"
@import "compass/css3/box-sizing"
@import "compass/css3/opacity"
@import "compass/layout/sticky-footer"
@import "compass/utilities"

// grid

@import "susy"



// application -----------------------------------------------------------------


// base

// for mixins, variables and helpers to aid in building
// the application. no styling of actual elements should
// go in base.

@import "base/colors"
@import "base/fonts"
@import "base/mixins"
@import "base/grid"


// layout

// generic site styles. this includes site chrome styles
// such as the header, footer, flash messages, nav, as well
// as common patterns used around the site like forms, type,
// links, etc. the loose idea is that you could take these
// styles and create a similar "layout" but it wouldn't
// include contextual patterns like books, originals, etc.

@import "layout/buttons"
@import "layout/content"
@import "layout/header"
@import "layout/flash"
@import "layout/forms"
@import "layout/footer"
@import "layout/links"
@import "layout/tooltips"
@import "layout/typography"


// modules

// elements used on multiple pages that are loosely tied
// to our domain and data structure. examples are dependent
// on the needs of your site. as a general guideline, all 
// modules should be used on multiple pages. elements used 
// on a single page should be included in views.

@import "modules/articles"
@import "modules/buttons"
@import "modules/forms"
@import "modules/links"
@import "modules/pagination"
@import "modules/users"
@import "modules/stats"
@import "modules/some_other_domain_specific_styling_unique_to_your_site"


// views

// elements used on a single page. these styles are
// often needed to help put finishing touches on a
// page where modules didn't quite line up perfectly,
// or where a page has completely unique elements.
// these styles could often be abstracted to modules
// but lack a reason to do so. keeping them here helps
// explain their singular usage.

@import "views/welcome/index"
@import "views/settings/all"
@import "views/articles/show"
@import "views/users/show"
```

Organizing your styles in this manner helps to create a single responsibility for each file (which it looks like you are trying to do as well). I've found that this makes your CSS a lot more maintainable. Also, if you need to add media queries or target a specific browser with a given module it gives you a place to do so that is contextually relevant while still keeping your code legible and separate.

Note, the example above would be used if you only had one namespace. If you had an admin section (or something else) you could stick all of these directories/files inside of an "application" directory and create a similar structure for "admin". This would leave you with the following structure in `app/stylesheets`.

```
- admin
- application
- admin.sass
- application.sass
```

You could even create a structure to share items between the two, but that may or may not be necessary. The point is that you have a lot of flexibility and organization for whatever you may need to do. This same structure can also be used for JS if you were so inclined. This circumvents the issue of reloading modules and making new requests.

FWIW, I tried to find a solution to bringing in only what I need per page (your question) but in the end I just ended up passing more bits on the whole while simultaneously increasing my number of requests. YMMV.

Hope this helps to get you on your way!